# Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in ionic

Tags: ios, api, web-services, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

[Error] Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

this error can be get on ionic applications when your trying to call web services (Http requests)

Answer (score 1):

to sort out this issue easily place below codes to your api web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

you have to give access from server side then only app can use post or get apis